# ftype long path name support

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

I have windows 10 with long pathname support. I have a command line that works great (running from windows powershell ISE):

```
>PS C:\> & 'C:\bin\TraceTester.exe' /FU C:\1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333\4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444\55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555\missed_cmdsn.tgd\missed_cmdsn.tgp
```

The file is opened by my tool and all is good.

But, I have an issue with double clicking on these files from explorer or other file managers.

I have ftype configured like this:

```
C:\>ftype trcFile="C:\bin\TraceTester.exe" "/FU %1"

trcFile="C:\bin\TraceTester.exe" "/FU %1"
```

However, when I double click on the file from explorer.exe or Explorer++ (both appear to be long path aware) I get this as the input to my program:
C:\111111~1\222222~1\333333~1\444444~1\555555~1\MISSED~1.TGP

It does open the file, but it's using the short name. Any idea how to get the OS/explorer to pass the long name? So, I'd see the 800+ char string in argv[2]?

(bonus points: any idea why long path support can't be enabled in the latest versions of windows 11?)

Comment: Have you set a manifest property indicating your app can support it?

Comment: Sorry, never got notified that anyone responded to this question. I'm still seeing the issue. I think the manifest is good to go with long filename support, but maybe I've goofed something up. Here's the manifest I'm using:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
<ws2:longPathAware xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</ws2:longPathAware>
<dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
<activeCodePage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">UTF-8</activeCodePage>
</windowsSettings>
</application>
</assembly>